# How can i share Magento Wishlist on Facebook

Tags: magento-1.9, wishlist

This question has been asked before over [Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/38437/how-to-share-wishlist-in-magento) but no answers were given. I have got the same task and am bit stuck on sharing.

Basically, i have to share the wishlist on Facebook. Just sharing link isn't enough as the wishlist can't be access without customer login.

I also tried sharing the wishlist using share URL which i retrieved using below code. But it is not working:

```
<?php echo Mage::getUrl('*/shared/index', array('code' => $this->getWishlistInstance()->getSharingCode())) ?>
```

Can anyone give an idea regarding how this can be achieved or clue from where should i start.

Comment: Would removing the logged in restriction work for you?

Comment: Arrr...never mind. I've re-read the question. I misunderstood something the first time. Sorry.

Comment: okay.. i am stucked finding the way across it.. Please let me know if you have some idea in your mind

Answer (score 1):

I did something like that, you have to save your wishlist before sharing the link.

So I overwrite the IndexController in the Wishlist to add a function that saves the wishlist.

Copy the

> code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php

to

> code/local/Mage/Wishlist/controller/IndexController.php

and at the end paste this function (is the update function with some modifications)

```
public function sharedirectAction()
    {
        if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
            return $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }

        $wishlist = $this->_getWishlist();
        if (!$wishlist) {
            return $this->norouteAction();
        }

        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if($post && isset($post['description']) && is_array($post['description'])) {
            $updatedItems = 0;

            foreach ($post['description'] as $itemId => $description) {
                $item = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->load($itemId);
                if ($item->getWishlistId() != $wishlist->getId()) {
                    continue;
                }

                // Extract new values
                $description = (string) $description;
                if (!strlen($description)) {
                    $description = $item->getDescription();
                }

                $qty = null;
                if (isset($post['qty'][$itemId])) {
                    $qty = $this->_processLocalizedQty($post['qty'][$itemId]);
                }
                if (is_null($qty)) {
                    $qty = $item->getQty();
                    if (!$qty) {
                        $qty = 1;
                    }
                } elseif (0 == $qty) {
                    try {
                        $item->delete();
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        Mage::logException($e);
                        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(
                            $this->__('Can\'t delete item from wishlist')
                        );
                    }
                }

                // Check that we need to save
                if (($item->getDescription() == $description) && ($item->getQty() == $qty)) {
                    continue;
                }
                try {
                    $item->setDescription($description)
                        ->setQty($qty)
                        ->save();
                    $updatedItems++;
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(
                        $this->__('Can\'t save description %s', Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($description))
                    );
                }
            }

            // save wishlist model for setting date of last update
            if ($updatedItems) {
                try {
                    $wishlist->save();
                    Mage::helper('wishlist')->calculate();
                }
                catch (Exception $e) {
                    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError($this->__('Can\'t update wishlist'));
                }
            }

        }

        try {
            $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();

            $sharingCode = $wishlist->getSharingCode();

            $wishlist->setShared(1);
            $wishlist->save();
            $this->_redirect('*//*', array('wishlist_id' => $wishlist->getId()));
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('wishlist/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

and now in your view.phtml add this jquery code, this add the action that we just create to your form and then submit it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
           var shareURL = '<?php echo Mage::getUrl('*/shared/index', array('code' => $this->getWishlistInstance()->getSharingCode())) ?>';
            var fbUrl = "javascript:popWin('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="+shareURL+"', 'facebook', 'width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');";
            jQuery('button.btn-share-facebook').attr("onclick", fbUrl); 
            jQuery('button.btn-share-facebook').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                jQuery('#wishlist-view-form').attr("action","<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/sharedirect') ?>");
                jQuery('#wishlist-view-form').submit();
            });
        });
```

I don't know if is the best way, but this works for me.